# I am trying to iterate through an array, and do something different if an element appears more than once?

Tags: java

I am trying to iterate over an array called students

```
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < students.length - 1; i1++) {
   for (int j = i + 1; j < students.length; j++) {
        if (i1 == j) {
```

If the element in the array appears the first time I want to "do something" and when it appears the second time "I want to do something else"

Comment: you don't need a second nested loop for this. You just need some data structure / way to remember which stundents you already came across once.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Maybe any structure that not allows duplicates...

Comment: You're comparing the indexes ... and not the element of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep a set of items you have already seen while iterating. Something along the lines:

```
Set<Student> seenStudents = new HashSet<>();
for (int index = 0; index< students.length; index++) {
    Student student = students[index];
    if (seenStudents.add(student)) {
       // do something
    } else {
       // I want to do something else
    }
}
```

The `Student` class (or whatever is the component type of `students`) must implement `hashCode` and `equals` for this to work.

Note that `// I want to do something else` will be executed on the 2nd, 3rd etc. occurence of the same `student`. If you want it to be executed only on the 2nd encounter, you'll need to count occurences (for instance in a `Map<Student, AtomicInteger>`). I think, however, that you don't interpret "the second time" too strict, so I'll leave it with the set.

Answer (score 0):

first pass store the values in a counter (hash map)

```
HashMap<String, Integer> counter =  new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < students.length ; i++){
    if (counter.get(students[i]) == null)
        counter.put(students[i], 1);
    else
       counter.put(students[i], counter.get(students[i]) + 1);
}
```

second pass to do some action based on the values freq

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.length ; i++){
    if (counter.get(students[i]) > 1)
       // do something
    else
       // do something else
 }
```

*assumed students array is String array*

Comment: If you replace `HashMap<String, Integer>` with `Map<String, AtomicInteger>`, you whole if/else construct could be reduced to `int count = counter.putIfAbsent(students[i], s -> new AtomicInteger(0)).incrementAndGet();`.

Comment: By the way `counter.get(students[i] + 1)` isn't correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
//this is an javascript code
var alreadyProccessedArrElem=[]

for (int i1 = 0; i1 < students.length - 1; i1++) 
{
    if(alreadyProccessedArrElem.length>0)
    {
        if(alreadyProccessedArrElem.indexOf(i1)<=-1)
        {
            var firstOccurence = students.indexOf(i1);
            var lastOccurence = students.lastIndexOf(i1);
            if(firstOccurence>-1)
            {
                //do something
            }
            if(lastOccurence>-1)
            {
                //do something else
            }
            alreadyProccessedArrElem.push(i1);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: There's no `push` in array in Java.

Comment: this is a java question

Answer (score -2):

Keep a comma delimited list of the occurrences. Count that every time you meet a new item in the array. Example (Pseudo Code Please).

```
var commalist = ""
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < students.length - 1; i1++) {
    commalist += (commalist.length > 0?",":"") + "'" + students[i1] + "'";

    <Count Occurences of 'Student_Name' into var occurrenceCount;>


    switch(occurrenceCount)
    {
        case 1:
            <First Action>
            break;
        case 2:
            <Second Action>
            break;
        case 3:
            <Third Action>
            break;  
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is extremely inefficient and fragile.